# I have a svg file containing data of a qr-code . How do i use it to print qr code on screen using python?

Tags: python, qr-code

I have a `SVG` file containing data of a QR-code. How do I use it to print QR code on the screen using python?

Comment: Please show what you have tried or considered.

Answer (score 0):

what ever you want to create in the qr code just do
first download pyqrcode, pyzbar, pillow with pip like so

```
$ pip install PyQRCode pyzbar pillow
```

import the lib

```
import pyqrcode
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image
```

then you instantiate the object with a passing data of what you want to encode in the create function

```
data = pyqrcode.create('hi')
#the data format is import
data.png('qrcode_img.png', scale=2)
#qr code image is created
decoded = decode(Image.open('qrcode_img.png'))
#your output console print contains a list of info encoded in your qrcode
print(decoded)
```

thanks [@OriginalGoldman](https://twitter.com/OriginalGoldman)